# Security concerns in long polling

Tags: long-polling, box-api

My understanding of long polling is that the server will keep the connection alive until there is some event. If we keep the port open, does it not make it vulnerable to security threats.

Answer (score 2):

Your system has a connection open to the Box server. Your system will not listen for new incoming requests on that port. Your connection is encrypted (HTTPS), so even a man-in-the-middle should not be able to mess with your stream.

As long as your SSL connection is not compromised, you are safe. If your SSL connections are getting compromised, you have bigger problems.